# What's the difference between the North Rim and the South Rim? (Grand Canyon)

Tags: las-vegas, grand-canyon

I'm from Australia trying hard to research a holiday do the Grand Canyon. I have 2 kids (7 & 4) and I know that the most common spot people go to it the South Rim. I'll also be travelling mid November.

I want to avoid bus tours and also know that from Las Vegas, the drive to the North Rim is roughly 4.5 hours and to the South Rim is roughly 4 hours.

Regarding view, accessibility and accommodation what's the difference?

Comment: probably all you need to know about the two: http://kaleidoscopicwandering.com/2011/02/07/south-rim-vs-north-rim-grand-canyon-national-park-arizona/

Comment: Tops! You could elaborate and add this into your answer.

Comment: For the record, since I'm also planning a trip there, the drive is slightly shorter from Phoenix, AZ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Services on the North Rim will be mostly shut by the time you arrive, they end in October (through pay at pump gas is still available some places).  The road itself stays open in November until enough snowfall accumulates to close it, then it remains closed until spring.  There will be no rooms available Grand Canyon Lodge at that time.

Lodging is still available on the South Rim and there are more things to access (sightseeing overlooks, trails, etc).  Crowds shouldn't be a big issue in mid-November.

Comment: Whether crowds are an issue is entirely in the eye fo the beholder.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Can you please specify when roads are open/closed and when services are open/closed and also what you mean by services? Lodges only? Shops? Information centers? Gas stations?

Comment: The lodge on the north rim usually shuts down around 15 Oct, the rest of services, stores, gas, visitor information shut down 31 Oct. The roads remain open until enough snow fall accumulates to warrant closing them.   (I understand that pay at the pump gas is still available inside the park until the roads are physically closed, but haven't been there in recent years during November to confirm)  The exact closing date for the roads is totally dependent on the weather and varies from year to year.  The roads do not reopen until spring.  A similar policy exists in Yellowstone National Park.